# Visual Studio 2010 can't open a web browser, tells me to restart Windows every time

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, browser

I'm trying to publish an Azure application, but can't sign in using Visual Studio 2010. I get the error message "The web browser cannot be started. To resolve this problem, you must restart Windows."

I've tried both rebooting and making Internet Explorer the default browser, but I still get the error message. This also occurs when clicking on other links (for example "Online Privacy Statement" in the same publish dialog box).

How can I fix this, or alternatively, are there any other easy ways to publish to Azure?

Comment: did you try to re-install Visual Studio ?

Comment: No, but that would be if I really can't find any other way..

Comment: Have you thought about using corepublish command line? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/02/15/decrypting-windows-azure-package-cspkg-in-windows-azure-sdk.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to publish to Azure. Depending on your preference, some of them may be easy. Some, not so much.

First of all, are you using a source control? If you're using git, then you can use Azure Git Repository that comes free with Azure Websites and also Azure Cloud Services. So when you push your code to the Azure repository, it automatically publishes the final bits to the corresponding site.

If you're using TFS locally (at home or office), you can set up a build task that'll deploy the bits to Azure. Also, check out [TFS Preview](http://tfspreview.com) if you are comfortable with a Microsoft hosted **free** TFS server.

If you feel comfortable using FTP, you can get the FTP account details from the Azure portal when you set up a new azure website or a cloud service.

Finally, one of the easiest way to publish to Azure is to use the Publish Profile feature.

1. You'll find a link called "Download Publish Profile" associated with
   your azure website. Click on that to download the profile (an XML
   file).
2. Then right click on your VS project and hit Publish. Under Profile
   tab, select "Import" and pick this downloaded file.
3. It should populate all the details for you. Test your connection to make sure everything works okay.
4. Publish and ENJOY!

**UPDATE:** Based on the comment to this answer, adding screenshot to show where to get the FTP details for your azure website.

[image]

Comment: I'm having a real hard time finding out where in Azure to get the FTP details (or much else, for that matter). The Azure documentation is also pretty scarce. Can you point me in some direction?

Comment: Check out the updated answer that has the screenshot to where you can find the FTP information for your azure website.

Comment: Thanks, I got it all working now. Nothing matched with my Azure until I realized you were using the preview dashboard :)